# Php. Fallo al comparar datos de un array

Tags: php, array, bucle-for

Estoy haciendo una página en php en la cual tengo que sacar los días laborales del calendario escolar. Tengo metido en un array los días festivos y en otro los sábados y domingos. Tengo un bucle que me recorre los días uno a uno y los compara con dichos arrays, y si el valor no está en ninguno, los imprime. Funciona con los fines de semana, pero no con los festivos. Aquí el código:

```
<?php
$start=strtotime('2019-09-11');
$end=strtotime('2020-05-29');
$meses=[
    '01'=>'Enero',
    '02'=>'Febrero',
    '03'=>'Marzo',
    '04'=>'Abril',
    '05'=>'Mayo',
    '06'=>'Junio',
    '07'=>'Julio',
    '08'=>'Agosto',
    '09'=>'Septiembre',
    '10'=>'Octubre',
    '11'=>'Noviembre',
    '12'=>'Diciembre',
];
$festivos=['2019-10-28','2019-10-29','2019-10-30','2019-10-31','2019-11-01','2019-12-06','2019-12-09','2019-12-23','2019-12-24','2019-12-25','2019-12-26','2019-12-27','2019-12-30','2019-12-31','2020-01-01','2020-01-02','2020-01-03','2020-01-06','2020-01-07','2020-02-24','2020-02-25','2020-02-26','2020-02-27','2020-02-28','2020-04-09','2020-04-10','2020-04-13','2020-04-14','2020-04-15','2020-04-16','2020-04-17','2020-05-01'];
$count=0;
$finde=[];
for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i+=24*60*60){
    if (date('D', $i)=='Sat' || date('D', $i)=='Sun'){
        $finde[]=(date('Y/m/d', $i));
    }
}
for($i=$start;$i<=$end;$i+=24*60*60){

    if ($i==$start){

        echo 'Comienzo del curso escolar';
        echo '</br>';
        echo '</br>';
        echo 'Septiembre';
        echo '</br>';
        echo '</br>';

    }


    if (date('d', $i)=='01'){

        echo '</br>';
        echo $meses[date('m', $i)];
        echo '</br>';
        echo '</br>';

    }

    if (!IN_ARRAY(date('Y/m/d', $i), $finde) || !IN_ARRAY(date('Y/m/d', $i), $festivos)){
        echo date('Y/m/d', $i);
        echo '</br>';
        $count++;
    }


    if ($i==$end){

        echo '</br>';
        echo '</br>';
        echo 'Fin del curso escolar';
        echo '</br>';
        echo 'Días lectivos: '.$count;

    }
}
 ?>
```

Lo suyo, lógicamente, es que filtre con ambos arrays.

Comment: Has probado a ver si es problema de que soy diferente tipo de objetos? En los fines de semana generas un objeto `date()` sin embargo en los festivos es un `string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El fallo es el separador de las fechas `/` o `-`.

Originalmente habías puesto `!IN_ARRAY(date('Y/m/d', $i), $festivos)` pero esto falla porque el separador de las fechas es `-` y no `/`.
 Lo podrías solucionar cambiando el separador en uno de los dos (El más sencillo en la sentencia if).

Otro problema que tienes es que al compararlos con una negación `!`, siempre entrará a menos que sea festivo y finde a la vez. Para esto en vez de utilizar el operador OR `||` utilizamos el operador AND `&&`

Al final la sentencia se quedaría de esta manera

```
if (!IN_ARRAY(date('Y/m/d', $i), $finde) || !IN_ARRAY(date('Y-m-d', $i), $festivos)){
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo has clavado en ambas. Probado y funcionando.